# Selected Item in Dropdown Lists in ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to select an element and return another element in View? Can I pass a key to a dictionary of c# in javascript razor?

```
// c# dictionary
dictionary dic
[localize("option1"), 1]
[localize("option2"), 2]
[localize("option3"), 3]
[localize("option4"), -1]

//razor code
@Html.DropDownList("options", new SelectList(dic.keys))
```

Then I want to get the value by the key `$('#options').val()` and pass it to the c# back from javascript json

Comment: What's the issue? Have you tried it? Also for `$('#options').val()` to work, you'd need to add an Id called 'options' to the dropdown.